# Blackbody Radiation Contradiction

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

Why does the graph of black body radiation come down after a maximum? Isn't it like supposed to 'blow up' to infinity, according to that equation $E = \sigma T^4$. How can the Wien distribution law be 'combined' with this to get Planck's equation of black body radiation? I watched a few videos and read some stuff on the net but it couldn't be explained satisfactorily.

Comment: The graph plotted is intensity Vs wavelength of light, not with temperature.

Comment: So basically you are searching a proof of Planck's law using Stefan's law ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, no. That is because there is a limit to type of radiation being emitted from an object. If the object is at Planck temperature then the emitted light will be so small. It will collapse into a black hole formed from pure light.